# The method 'clear_helpers' in ApplicationController - not found - method undefined for undefined method `user_signed_in?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I keep seeing this answer: 
"Try removing 'clear_helpers' method in ApplicationController as it might block sometimes Devise to load his helpers."

Well that'd be great *if it was actually there to remove.*

The point is to keep the blog page from being view until you log in and show other content in the mean time. (devise)

My page I'm getting the error on: http://pastebin.com/rFx17ecG
my application.rb: http://pastebin.com/MRCLVh0M

I see absolutely nothing that has to do with 'clear_helpers'. I need help and clarification, because doesn't seem like it exists..

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `user_signed_in?` you need to use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controller. Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

Comment: Well, the issue was i never ran rails g devise user (smh).
But even after that, I never had to utilize 'before_filter :authenticate_user!'(double checked to see it wasn't auto created or something weird.)Thank you for the help.